# Chrome browser not caching js files while debugging extjs application

Tags: extjs, extjs5

So far i was able to set

```html
'disableCaching: false'
```

in Ext.Loader.config(in app.js) and debug extjs applications on chrome browser. 
But now, on inspecting the source, i see that the files have filename.js?dc=1123123 and every time the files are fetched from remote and not cached. So i am unable to set breakpoints and debug run-time on browser.
Please note that this scenario is when i do a browser refresh.

Plz let me know how i can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Set [disableCacheing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-disableCaching) to `false` in `app.js` before `Ext.application({...`

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    disableCaching: false
});
```

This will remove _dc cache param from requests that are getting files.

For disabling _dc on XHR Ext.Ajax requests use

```
Ext.Ajax.disableCaching = false;
```

And for proxy communication with server use `noCache` property on `Ext.data.proxy.Server` class.

[noCache: true](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-noCache)

You can also set cache config in **app.json** file.

```
"loader": {
    // This property controls how the loader manages caching for requests:
    //
    //   - true: allows requests to receive cached responses
    //   - false: disable cached responses by adding a random "cache buster"
    //   - other: a string (such as the build.timestamp shown here) to allow
    //     requests to be cached for this build.
    //
    "cache": "${build.timestamp}",

    // When "cache" is not true, this value is the request parameter used
    // to control caching.
    //
    "cacheParam": "_dc"
}
```

Also if using Chrome Dev Tools for debugging take a look at [disableCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development) on Networks tab and if using FF use <kbd>CTRL + F5</kbd> insted <kbd>F5</kbd> to [reload](https://superuser.com/questions/23134/how-to-turn-off-the-firefox-cache) page

Comment: i have set disableCaching: false in Ext.Loader.setConfig. But i still see the _dc param for all requests(proxy json and js files).
also, the disable cache is unchecked in network tab in chrome debug. 
i still am unable to cache files.

Answer (score 1):

Add `?cache=false` to the end of your URL to temporarily disable caching on a per-request basis.

Comment: This along with "Disable Cache" checked in the Network tab of Chrome Devtools solves everything. API requests still have the caching parameter set, whereas regular JS files don't

Answer (score 0):

Setting Ext.Loader configuration is one thing. There is also something called `Ext.Boot` which is used before loader is up and running. Boot has his own `disableCaching` setting. It defaults to something like this:

```
disableCaching: (/[?&](?:cache|disableCacheBuster)\b/i.test(location.search) ||
    !(/http[s]?\:/i.test(location.href)) ||
    /(^|[ ;])ext-cache=1/.test(doc.cookie)) ? false :
    true,
```

Probably files with dc appended to url are loaded by `Boot`. If you want to disable it permanently just replace this code and set it to `false`.

Comment: do you want me to try this in application.js file:
`Ext.Boot.setConfig({
    disableCaching: false
});`

Answer (score 0):

app.json:

```
"loader": {"cache": true},
```

then:

```
sencha app refresh
```

it may seem confusing, but the _dc parameter then won't be present anymore - at all.